# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I have some problem when I set RecyclerViewAdapter

I get error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a
>   null object reference

in line `mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());`

How to fix it

```
for (ProfileFeedListModelTwo.PostBean.PollBean pollBean : pp){
   pollBeanArrayList.add(pollBean);}

 adapDetailTopicPoll = new AdapDetailTopicPoll(pollBeanArrayList,getContext());
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapDetailTopicPoll);
```

Comment: Try some of the other methods for retrieving the activity, like maybe `getParentActivity()`. Based on the error your getActivity() is null and probably not the right method to call in this case.

Comment: sorry my english is not good ,I do not understand what you're saying

Answer (score 3):

`getActivity()` is `null`. You are probably calling this method before your activity is attached to your fragment.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle):

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can
> call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only
> when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not
> yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle,
> getActivity() will return null

Try and understand the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) and how it is coupled with [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Please give example for me?

Comment: You are trying to add a fragment to an activity like this:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, (your_fragment)).commit();
and when you are trying to get the context the application crashes
first try to put this code in the onViewCreated() method in your fragment
then try to put getContext() instead of getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

just use only this
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()); and if you are writing this code in activity then use getApplicationContext()

Comment: it's not error ,but i get new error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'` in line `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);`